# Hi all, I want to minimize the code by removing switch case from this function as I have 100s of cases to be created. How can this be done?

Tags: java, switch-statement, cucumber, bdd

I want to remove this switch case from here to reduce the lines of code as I have 100s of cases to be maintained and in this case this switch case will become very lengthy and complex.

How to handle this without using switch-case or if-else loop. Please help.

**Feature File statement-**

```
When user click on "support" section and "supportDocs" subsection
```

**Step definition code-**

```
public void click_on_section_and_subsection(String sectionName, String subSectionName) {


        String mSectionName = sectionName.replaceAll("\\s", "").toLowerCase();
        LogBack.log.info("Modified section name: " + mSectionName);

        String mSubSectionName = subSectionName.replaceAll("\\s", "").toLowerCase();
        LogBack.log.info("Modified subsection name: " + mSubSectionName);

        switch (mSectionName) {
        case "support":

            staticPage.clickSupportTab();

            switch (mSubSectionName) {

            case "supporttickets":
                staticPage.clickSupportTicketsTab();
                break;

            case "supportdocs":
                staticPage.clickSupportDocsTab();
                break;

            case "apidocs":
                staticPage.clickApiDocsTab();
                break;
            }

            break;
        }
        utilsManager.seleniumUtils.refreshPage();

    }
```

**Static Page - Class**

```
public class StaticPage {   
    
    private WebDriver driver;
    private UtilsManager utilsManager;
    
    public StaticPage(WebDriver driver, UtilsManager utilsManager) {
        
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.utilsManager = utilsManager;
    }   
    
    //Locators Segment
    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[@id='lnk_Support']")
    WebElement SUPPORT_SECTION; // To click on Support Section/Menu
    
    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[@id='lnk_SupportTickets']")
    WebElement SUPPORT_TICKET_SUBSECTION; // To click on Support Ticket Subsection
    
    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[@id='lnk_SupportDocs']")
    WebElement SUPPORT_DOCS_SUBSECTION; // To click on Support Docs Subsection 
    
    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[@id='lnk_APIDocs']")
    WebElement API_DOCS_SUBSECTION; // To click on API Docs Subsection 
    
    
    
    // Action Segment   

        public void clickSupportTab(){

            utilsManager.seleniumUtils.waitForElementVisible(SUPPORT_SECTION, 20);
            utilsManager.seleniumUtils.waitForElementClickable(SUPPORT_SECTION, 20).click();
        }
    

        public void clickSupportTicketsTab() {
            utilsManager.seleniumUtils.waitForElementVisible(SUPPORT_TICKET_SUBSECTION, 20);
            utilsManager.seleniumUtils.waitForElementClickable(SUPPORT_TICKET_SUBSECTION, 20).click();          
        }

        public void clickSupportDocsTab() {
            utilsManager.seleniumUtils.waitForElementVisible(SUPPORT_DOCS_SUBSECTION, 20);
            utilsManager.seleniumUtils.waitForElementClickable(SUPPORT_DOCS_SUBSECTION, 20).click();            
        }
        
        public void clickApiDocsTab() {
            utilsManager.seleniumUtils.waitForElementVisible(API_DOCS_SUBSECTION, 20);
            utilsManager.seleniumUtils.waitForElementClickable(API_DOCS_SUBSECTION, 20).click();            
        }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, create a `Map` that correlates strings to a `Consumer` to simplify.

Example:

```
StaticPage x = new StaticPage(...);
Map<String, Consumer<StaticPage>> v = Map.of(
   "supporttickets", StaticPage::clickSupportTicketsTab(), 
   "supportdocs", StaticPage::clickSupportDocsTab(), ...);

v.getOrDefault("supporttickets", x -> {}).accept(u);
```

You must adapt the code to your needs, specially in the `Map` creation part, since `Map.of` can create only a limited number of entries.